# Validate input of any two specific letters say 'a' and 'i' in JavaScript and replace 'a' with @ and 'i' with?

Tags: javascript, regex, performance, validation, replace

I'm a  newbie and need help here.
We need a input string from an user. 
The input string must contain both letters `'a'` and `'i'`. If it doesn't contain both then we reject the input and alert the user.

If the input string contains both `'a'` and `'i'` then we replace `a with @ and i with !`.We then print the output.

For example: `aletis-->@lert!s`

I tried

```
var check = /[aiAI]/;
```

but this takes input even if only either a or i is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really new with regex, I would advise you to do it in two steps,as this would be far more clear to read.

```js
"alertis".replace(/a/gi, "@").replace(/i/gi, "!");
```

/a/gi means find "a" with the /gi meaning "case insensitive" and global.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (/(?=.*a)(?=.*i).*/.test('aletis')) {
    const result = "aletis".replace(/a/gi, "@").replace(/i/gi, "!");
    // Rest of your code
} else {
    // SHOW ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use includes and replace

- First get the value of input element
- Change to lowercase and check if both `a` and `i` exists or not
- If exists replace `a` and `i` by respective values

```js
function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let element = document.getElementById('input').value
  let lowerCased = element.toLowerCase()
  if (lowerCased.includes('a') && lowerCased.includes('i')) {
    console.log(element.replace(/a/gi, '@').replace(/i/gi, '!'))
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit='handleSubmit(event)'>
  <input id='input'>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```